# (click) event does not work on FixedColumns in dataTable.net in angular 5

Tags: angular

I am facing problem of (click) event of angular on FixedColumns in dataTable. When column is fixed or freeze angular 5 click event does not work. However it works if column is not fixed or freeze. Anyone faced similar issue or knows solution for the same ?

I am using [https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/] data table in my code. Here is my component.ts and html file

> ```
> ngOnInit() {
>     this.dtOptions =  {  
>       pagingType: 'full_numbers' ,
>       paging : true,
>       searching : true,
>       processing: false,
>       responsive: false,
>       scrollX:true,
>       scrollY:'250px',
>       scrollCollapse:true,
>       fixedColumns:   {
>         leftColumns: 1,
>         rightColumns: 1
>       },
>       columnDefs: [ 
>         {
>           "searchable": false,
>           "orderable": false,
>           "targets": [0, 1]  
>         }
>       ],
>       order: [[2, 'asc']],
>    };
>
>   this.dataMgmtService.getWorksheetData(0).subscribe(response => {
>         this.serviceOrderData = response;
>         if(this.serviceOrderData[0]) {
>           this.tableHeaders = this.objectKeys(this.serviceOrderData[0]);
>           console.log(this.objectKeys(this.serviceOrderData[0]));
>           console.log(this.serviceOrderData[0]);
>           this.dtTrigger.next();
>         } 
>       },
>       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error, 
>     ); 
>   }
>
> hideShowRow(event){ 
>     alert('Not getting called');
>     this.getDatableRowFromTR(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement);
>
>   }
> ```

HTML File

> ```
> <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"  class="row-border hover">
>   <thead>
>     <tr>
>       <th style="background-color: #fff;">&nbsp;</th>
>       <th style="background-color: #fff;"><input type="checkbox"/></th>
>       <th style="background-color: #fff;" *ngFor="let tableHead of tableHeaders">{{tableHead | uppercase }}</th>
>     </tr>
>   </thead>
>   <tbody>
>     <tr *ngFor="let row of serviceOrderData; let i = index" >
>       <td><a #input class="detail-icon" href="javascript:;" (click)="hideShowRow($event)"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></td>
>       <td style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
>       <td *ngFor="let col of objectValues(row); let j = index">{{ col }}</td>
>     </tr>
>   </tbody>
> </table>
> ```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGZWW.png)

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Could you let folks know more about the reference to "FixedColumns in dataTable"? Is that a third party component / package or something you're using? If so which one? Can the issue be reproduced?

Comment: Can you include code samples so we can review?